# Updating a Counter to Firestore

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to have a Counter that counts every time I click on the Button

Therefore I have following Code to create the Button

```
 func configureButton() -> UIButton{
    button.setTitle("drink", for: .normal)
    button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "beer-2288121_640").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleDrinkButton), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.backgroundColor = .black
    button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    
    return button
}
```

Also I have a public variable for the Counter

```
var beer: Int?
```

And than I want to get and push the Data to Firebase

```
  @objc func handleDrinkButton() {
    
   var db = Firestore.firestore()
   
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
   
    self.beer =  db.collection("users").document(userID!).collection("beer") as! Int
      
        self.beer! += 1
        
        Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(userID!).updateData(["beer": self.beer])

      // ...
      }){ (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of the Database]

But the Data does not change.

I don't know if I am increasing the number false or read and write the data the wrong way.

Comment: Your code is *reading* from the Realtime Database, and then writing to Cloud Firestore. Is that intentional?

Comment: thank you, I have edited the comment for Firestore

Comment: But I think it is the wrong way to assign the User Data to an Integer. I have the following error message: Cannot assign value of type 'CollectionReference' to type 'Int'

Comment: Maybe something like 
        
        
        self.beer = dbRef.collection("beer") as? Int ?? 0
        
        
            self.beer! += 1

Answer (score 0):

The `beer` in your collection is not a *collection*, but it's a field inside a document.

If you want to increase that field's value, Firestore has a built-in `increment` operation that makes this much easier:

```
db.collection("users").document(userID!).updateData([
    "beer": FieldValue.increment(Int64(1))
])
```

Also see:

- The documentation on [incrementing a value](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value).